# MQ JMS Message ID returns no text message and how to write the MQ JMSCorrelationID in proper format

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I tested a standalone JMS client passing a `TextMessage` to a queue on IBM MQ, and I got the below message id with error:

> ID:414d51204243573032413154202020205bc6bd3e25423865
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: no text message

1. I sent a `TextMessage` with `This is for Test`, but why didn't I receive a `TextMessage`? There were no other messages in the queue before this code ran.
2. In case text message success how to read the message Id  (send request MessageID  and reply message Id) in readable format in Java. Is any thing I need to change in the below code.

```
TextMessage textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage("This is for Test");
textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
textMessage.setJMSType("mcd://xmlns");//message type
textMessage.setJMSExpiration(2*1000);//message expiration
textMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT); 
queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queueSession.createQueue(outputQName));
queueSender.setTimeToLive(2*1000);
queueSender.send(textMessage);

String jmsCorrelationID = " JMSCorrelationID = '" + textMessage.getJMSMessageID() + "'";
while (true) {                        
    Message message = queueReceiver.receive(60*1000);
    if (! (message instanceof TextMessage))
        throw new RuntimeException("no text message");
    TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) message;
    System.out.println("Message:"+tm.getText());  
}
```

Comment: Which broker service?

Comment: Receive call has returned. Meaning it has found a message. Are you sure there are no other messages in the queue before you sent a message?

Comment: For messageid see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729239/get-mq-messageid-in-string-format

Comment: IBM MQ broker service

Comment: Yes no other messages in the queue before you sent a message

Comment: Maxtech, if a question is related to any specific MQ provider it is best to add the provider specific tag not the generic [mq] tag.  I have edited a few of your questions recently and replaced [mq] with [ibm-mq].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this simply be that your message is expiring from the queue?

I see you set the message expiry to 2 seconds.  Many replying applications will copy the remaining expiry value to the reply message.  So if the app that reads the request and sends you the reply does not read your request within 2 seconds from the time it was sent, or if it does and replies with the remaining expiry and the reply does not make it back to be consumed by you, it would disappear from the queue.

Try increasing the expiry time to a higher value.

---

Also note you are setting the same expiry value via two different methods, one is meant to be a default for all messages sent by the producer and the other is a per message setting.

This sets a default expiry on all messages sent by the producer:

```
queueSender.setTimeToLive(2*1000);
```

This sets the expiry on the specific message you are sending and would override the `queueSender.setTimeToLive`, so you only need one of these lines.

```
textMessage.setJMSExpiration(2*1000);//message expiration
```

Comment: Thanks please correct me whether my understand is correct. You mean that first I need to increase the expiry value second I need to use either one of them textMessage.setJMSExpiration(2*1000) or queueSender.setTimeToLive(2*1000); So what would happen If I keep only textMessage.setJMSExpiration(2*1000) to expire specific message what I am sending and comment out queueSender.setTimeToLive(2*1000); how long the message occurs

Comment: The expiry is 2 seconds if you set one, the other, or both.   There is no benefit to setting both do just pick one.

Comment: Why do you want it to expire in 2 seconds?

Comment: correct me default how long to store or what is the best way whether expire or not if not how to set

Comment: How can I correct you if I don't know what you are attempting to do.  If you do not want it to expire in 2 seconds then increase the TimeToLive/JMSExpiration.  If you don't want it to expire, then don't set those.  The value of those settings in in milliseconds (1000 milliseconds/second).  You specified 2*1000, that is 2000 milliseconds or 2 seconds.

Comment: Thans JoshMc now i understand

Comment: Note that normally you would not wait longer to receive the message than the expiry.  In your example you wait 60 seconds `receive(60*1000)` for the response, but you set only a 2 second expiry on your request, so you are waiting for 58 seconds longer than you specified for your request to expire.  Unless you have some specific purpose to set it to 2 seconds, that seems like a very low number.  You say you are updating a database, I would expect that is usually something you would not want to expire.

Comment: yes I am updating the reply message in database so as per your suggestion i will change the expiry code textMessage.setJMSExpiration(0) that means if i add  zero it won't expire please correct me

Comment: Thanks JoshMc for all your reply helped me lot

Answer (score 0):

In your request-reply use-case the kind of message the *requesting* client sends has no direct bearing on the kind of message it will receive. The kind of message the requesting client receives depends on what the *responding* client sends.

As for getting the message ID as a `String` from the IBM MQ implementation you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729239/get-mq-messageid-in-string-format).

Answer (score 0):

Is your session transactional?
If yes then your message is not "visible" on the queue until the transaction is "commit" and you never `commit`...
I'm curious to know what is the content of`message` when you test its class..is it null?
Does the `receive`return immediately or only after the timeout expired (in your case 60*1000ms)?
Denis

Comment: The message return immediately and I am doubt they are expecting message in some format and if that format not there they are not send message correct me

Comment: I read the message data from database and pass the data one one I written in my code queueConnection.createQueueSession(false,
     Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); that means not transactional correct, please correct me so in my case do i need transactional or not transactional if transactional i need to change code  as 
 below queueConn.createQueueSession(true,         Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE); and then to queueSession.commit();

Comment: If the transacted field is true then second field does not matter, it is ignored, it only applies if transacted is false.  There is a special value `Session.TRANSACTED` that you can use in the second field to indicated that that the session is TRANSACTED, but this is just a placeholder and does nothing beyond setting Transacted to true.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks. if I set (true, Session.TRANSACTED) do I need queuesession.commit correct me

Comment: Yes,  anytime it is transacted you need commit.