# Setting targetClient=1 changes the JMSCorrelationID value

Tags: java, ibm-mq

We are setting `queue.setTargetClient(1)` and `JMSCorrelationID` from application side. Once response comes application in MQ, we `JMSCorrelationID` value populated as HEX value.

For now, I am using the following selector pattern:

`corlID = "JMSCorrelationID='ID:" + Hex.encodeHexString(corl.getBytes())+"'";`

Do we know why this happening?

Comment: What is the question.  What is unexpected about the behavior that you see?

Comment: We are expecting that JMSCorrelationID should be in String format and not in Hex

Comment: The underlying ID field in MQ is a byte field, not a string field, so the only sensible way to represent it as a string is in HEX.  How you are doing it looks normal.

Comment: See if this answer helps at all "[Get MQ messageId in string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729239/get-mq-messageid-in-string-format/45741083#45741083)".